# Ignore hosts file?

Tags: c#, hosts

I need to call a Response.Redirect method from C# but I need to do it in such a way that it ignores the Hosts file on windows for this call?

For example, if on Hosts I have:

127.0.0.1 google.com

and I call a Response.Redirect("google.com"), I need it to ignore the hosts just for this one call and actually go to google.com rather than localhost. How could I do this?

I know I could call a Response.Redirect on google's IP address but is there a better way?

Comment: "I know I could call a Response.Redirect on google's IP address" - how are you going to find out what that IP address is? On a system with that entry in hosts, it will always tell you 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @AakashM: well, you *could* open a socket, make an `A` query to a DNS server yourself (try Google's 8.8.8.8 if you won't bother with system settings), parse the returned data and voila, there's the IP address. In other words, bypass the OS's DNS resolver and do it yourself. As you can see, no `hosts` file involved; reinventing the wheel, OTOH, that might be a bit of an issue.

Comment: @Piskvor wow yes OK that would work. But if I saw an app successfully locating google while I had that entry in my hosts file I'd be... *surprised*, to say the least :)

Comment: @AakashM: True, it would be unexpected, suspicious, and impractical; all this said, it would still be technically possible.

Answer (score 3):

No, probably not: DNS lookup is handed over to your OS, which checks...`hosts` file.

Iff you can

- look up the IP address without the OS's resolver
- *and* the target server accepts IP address instead of hostname (some webservers will refuse to serve `http://10.15.6.4/some/path` (Google Search accepts an IP hostname and works, btw)),

then it might work.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to ignore the hosts file is to delete it.

Comment: Or comment out the offending line. Anyway, some programs (e.g. web browsers) keep their own DNS cache in addition to the OS's resolver, so changes to `hosts` aren't guaranteed to "take" immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you can know the IP address of the host without asking the OS ( e.g. via 3rd party ) .. then you actually ignored the hosts files .